# Check if an email exists in PHP

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm developing an hotel booker and I need to know if an email exists, else I can't write the confirmation to the user and I can't comunicate with him. I've found a lot of PHP classes that do this work but no one of them do this is the right way; do you know a way to do this?

Comment: Send them an email with an activation link. Tack that link click on your end. That's the only way to know for sure the email exists and the user controls it.

Comment: This is called Double Opt-In and is absolutely required if you wish to be a reputable sender of commercial email. So much so, in fact, that it has been codified into law in some countries.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you could do that would work in a feasible way would be something like:

1. Check if the mail has a valid format.
2. Send a verification e-mail for the user to confirm the e-mail.
3. Once the user verifies you know you can communicate, otherwise you don't let them continue using your service.